# Is celestial spirit magic exclusive to females?

Tags: fairy-tail

In the fairy tail universe, we see female celestial mages like Lucy, Yukino, Lyla, Sorano, etc, but we do not see any male characters with celestial spirit magic. So is the celestial spirit magic exclusive to females or are there male celestial spirit mages also?

Comment: As stated in Parth Srivastav's answer, Duke Everlue (the previous owner of virgo's key) is a celectial wizard shown in the early chapters of Fairytail.

Comment: That’s not true. Everlue opened Virgos gate. So he obviously was using Celestial Spirit Magic. Although his primary magic of choice was his Digger Magic. It’s not like we havent seen other wizards using more than one type of magic. So I guess the answer is no. It’s not exclusive to females.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Celestial Spirit Magic is a type of Magic in which the user summons Celestial Spirits by opening their gates through the use of Celestial Spirit Gate Keys. These Keys are separated into two classes: the more common Silver Keys and the rarer Gold Keys. Keys for Celestial Spirits are counted in Units (collectively without regard of Gold or Silver), and a Celestial Spirit Mage is noted by how many Units they have obtained.

Celestial Spirit Magic is not exclusive to women, although the majority of users shown in the manga are women.

For instance [Everlue](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Everlue) and [Zoldio](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Zoldeo) are two male characters who have used Celestial Spirit magic in the manga thus far.

Complete list of users http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Celestial_Spirit_Magic

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There are too many female celestial mages that I totally forgot about Everlue and Zoldio.